# Should action creator trigger another action?

Tags: reactjs-flux, flux

For example, I am going to implement a "Like post" feature. After the post is liked, then I need to get the latest like count (another action).

From the following code, should I call get(postId) immediately to trigger another action or should store trigger that when handling "LIKE_POST_SUCCESS". Can a store trigger an action?

```
class PostActions {
    like(postId) {
        var self = this;
        PostApiUtils.like(postId).then(function() {
            AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                actionType: 'LIKE_POST_SUCCESS',
                postId: postId
            });
            self.get(postId);
        });
    }

    get(postId) {
        PostApiUtils.get(postId).then(function(post) {
            AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                actionType: 'GET_POST_SUCCESS',
                post: post
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stores should never trigger actions, while actions may trigger other actions. So your code looks fine to me. In your store, where you are handling `LIKE_POST_SUCCESS`, you could `waitFor` `GET_POST_SUCCESS` before emitting a change.

Comment: Thanks. You reminded me that I can emit the change after GET_POST_SUCCESS.